# css gradient with image strip height issue

Tags: design-patterns, css, linear-gradients

How could I use my linear-gradient pattern strip,mystrip.jpg (1x1024 px), to be the body background of my web page? I need to repeat itself horizontally and have its height 100% of the body height.

I tried with

```
body{background:url(mystrip.jpg) repeat-x;}
```

but whenever my body content is exceding 1024px height,I can see clearly the bottom border of my strip pattern.

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a background colour that matches the bottom color.

```
body{background: #f00 url(mystrip.jpg) repeat-x;}
```

Or whatever the colour is.

Alternatively you can use background-size, but that likely won't make it look good.

I'd recommend using CSS gradients where possible as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should set a background color also, so that where the image ends, the color takes over. Make the background color the same as the bottom color of your image.

Example:

```
body{ background: #ccc url(mystrip.jpg) repeat-x; }
```

Comment: Thanks I just needed a reference!